# Rails with bootstrap-generators gem has zero styling in IE8 but does in IE9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

Using

```
gem 'bootstrap-generators', '~> 2.0'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 2.0'
```

Bootstrap style is non-existant in IE9 and under, but shows fine in IE10 via http://netrenderer.com/.

my bootstrap-generators.css.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap-variables";

body {
  padding-top: $navbarHeight + 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.page-header {
  a.btn {
    float: right;
  }

  a.btn + a.btn {
    margin-right: 8px;
  }
}

@import "scss/bootstrap";
@import "scss/responsive";
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there a `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is described here [Rails 3.1, assets pipeline and IE 6 & 7 in production mode - some CSS & js are not loaded properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621189/rails-3-1-assets-pipeline-and-ie-6-7-in-production-mode-some-css-js-are-n)

We had to split up the css, and now all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are using HTML5 elements that IE8 can't process for example `<section>`.
Try adding this to the `<head>` of the layout file

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

If it renders correctly, that was your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I already had it. Checking with http://netrenderer.com/ IE 10 shows fine, every other version shows without any style. A theory someone just mentioned to me was that it could be a missing closing tag somewhere. I believe firefox and probably others automatically add them to fix issues like this, but possibly IE does not, and maybe they just added that feature to IE10. Any other ideas?

Comment: That sounds totally possible too.  Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307178/any-tools-to-find-missing-html-tags